# Counting an Occurrence in an SArray (Python)

Tags: python

I want to count the number of occurrence of "1"  in

```
x = graphlab.SArray([-1, -1, 1, 1, 1])
```

I tried `x.count("1")` but it gives this error message:

> AttributeError: 'SArray' object has no attribute 'count'

How can I count the occurrences of some value in an SArray?

Comment: What is an SArray?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see here on how to provide a reproducible example, which will help us help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: SFrame and SArray are scalable data structure for dealing with big tables of data, they do not have to fit in computer memory. You have to import Graphlab package in order to have them.